# How to select the inner elements' text in GEB?

Tags: html, css, grails, spock, geb

I have the following scenario:

```
<div>
    <ul class="select2-results" style="width: 400px;">
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">
                <span id="12345" class="null">
                    GBP
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">
                <span id="45678" class="null">
                    KPW
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">
                <span id="12345" class="null">
                    USD
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to select the currencies from it. I was trying the following thing but no way:

```
assert $('UL.select2-results LI.select2-results-dept-0.select2-result.select2-result-selectable', 0..2)*.text() == ["GBP", "KPW", "USD"]
```

Even I could not handle this one:

```
assert $('UL.select2-results LI.select2-results-dept-0.select2-result.select2-result-selectable')*.size() == 3
```

Though, I can handle a single element:

```
assert $('UL.select2-results').find("LI.select2-results-dept-0.select2-result.select2-result-selectable", 0).text() == "GBP"
```

Any help or suggestion would be really beneficial for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why @Gabriel's answer did not work! I know there was an issue with 0..3 as it would be 0..2! But instead of find it finally worked:

```
assert $('UL.select2-results LI.select2-results-dept-0.select2-result.select2-result-selectable span')*.text() == ["GBP", "KPW", "USD"]
```

I would love to see if anyone can explain why indexing+using find+* did not work together for this particular problem or was there any logical syntax related problem.

Comment: Well at least you found a solution! Be sure to mark it as the right answer so others know not to try and solve it for you.

Comment: I will do that for sure. I also found the solution for the question you asked and deleted yesterday! I was about to paste it as answer and your question was gone!

Comment: Hah, really? Yeah, I just needed to upgrade Geb to the next teeny rev. Funny.

Comment: Really, you had a problem with string.

Comment: Ah, there may have been a typo in my example, but the base issue was that Geb added support for `has()` to have multiple parameters in 0.9.1 (e.g. `.has('p', foo:'bar')`. In 0.9.0 it would only support the tag name, e.g. `.has('p')`.

Comment: yes, you are correct! You can not use multiple parameters/properties as you were trying to do so :)

Answer (score 3):

Just by eyeballing your example, what you're getting back is 3 `DIV`s. It looks like you need to go a bit deeper, adding a `.find('span')` just before your asterisk.

```
assert $(
   'UL.select2-results LI.select2-results-dept-0.select2-result.select2-result-selectable',
    0..3)*.text() == ["GBP", "KPW", "USD"]
```

becomes

```
assert $(
   'UL.select2-results LI.select2-results-dept-0.select2-result.select2-result-selectable',
    0..3).find('span')*.text() == ["GBP", "KPW", "USD"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you might be able to simplify how you get the currencies by doing the following:

```
$("div.select2-result-label").children("span")*.text() == ["GBP", "KPW", "USD"]
```

Because you already have classes on the divs, you can easily access them using the above selector, then you can get the children *span* elements and get the text of each span. I hope this helps!