# Not quite sure how to find the locator using Geb without using nth-child

Tags: geb

I have to find a better locater per my co-workers suggestion as they do not want me to use nth-child locators which will make my test more brittle.  I am really struggling trying to write this particular locator to access the following code which is dynamic content.

I have tried the following:

```groovy
flipperCardOne(wait: true, waitCondition: {
    it.displayed
}) {
    $(class: "h3", class: "info-card-name", text: "Mandy Smith)
}
```

and

```groovy
flipperCardOne(wait: true, waitCondition: {
    it.displayed
}) {
    $(class: "flex-item.front > .w-100", text: "Mandy Smith")
}
```

But it's not quite right.

```html
<div _ngcontent-vho-c20="" class="flex-item">
   <!---->
   <u-flippy-card _ngcontent-vho-c20="" _nghost-vho-c24="" flipped="false">
      <!---->
      <div _ngcontent-vho-c24="" class="flipper">
         <div _ngcontent-vho-c24="" class="front w-100"><img _ngcontent-vho-c24="" class="w-100" src="assets/images/life/mandy_smith.jpg"></div>
         <div _ngcontent-vho-c24="" class="back w-100 info-card">
            <p _ngcontent-vho-c24="" class="info-card-quote”>”TESTING.”</p><h4 _ngcontent-vho-c24="" class="info-card-name">Mandy Smith
            </h4>
         </div>
      </div>
   </u-flippy-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select the inner elements' text in GEB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027890/how-to-select-the-inner-elements-text-in-geb)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're looking for h3 when the tag is a h4.

If the text "Mandy Smith" is a constant then you can just locate by text value:

```
{ $('h4').find(text: 'Mandy Smith') }
```

Comment: What I posted is actually not quite correct.  I'm closer but still not quite there.  I figured out that I can't look for that text when the u-flippy-card = "false" as the text only appears when u-flippy-card = "true".

Comment: I now have this:   flipperCardOne(wait:true) {$ ( ".flex-item.front.w-100, 5")} but not sure if that is how you call the nth-child(5)